# most efficient way of Storing XY & Z image filenames

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

Good Morning,

I am about to start working on a little personal project which will basically consist of a camera hooked up to a microscope, where I move the X and Y stage, and will eventually move the Z stage (Focus / Depth).

The project will incorporate a digital camera SDK, so I can capture images and will assign them a filename but my question is what is the most efficient way to store the filename as for each X and Y position on the Z axis I may collect anywhere from 1 to lots of images which I will stack together later on through external software to create one focus stacked image for each X & Y point.

So my question is, what is the best way to be able to store the names of the files, is an array the best way to go? or are there better options (e.g. structured list of classes with a Z list)?

Appreciate any feedback, as I am trying to get the foundation of storing the data correct, given there may be lots of image references stored.

At the end, once the capture had completed (or potentially during) I would then loop through the Z dimension of each array / structured list and feed the filename references to an external program, take the stacked image and then feed that reference back into another ZY array or list (whatever is most efficient).

Should clarify as well I am working in vb.net

Many thanks!

Update:

Thanks all, to clarify I will store the images in the filesystem but keep the reference of the file (e.g. the filename) in the array. The system will only have one X and Y coordinate per overall image, but there may be many Z.

So the flow would be:

Start at position 1,1 then take 10 photos of differing Z depths storing the file names in the array

Move to position 1,2 then take 10 photos and so on.

The system would then stitch together each of the Z depths at each x,y point to make one image, and then I would use that image (from each X,Y point) and stitch it together into one bigger image

Comment: Its a pretty broad question, but I would not assume that there will be one X per Y per Z.  There might be several per "take".  Forego the array and base it on a `List(Of T)`.  I might use a class to keep X, Y and Z together, where each of *them* is a `List(Of String)` then a `List(Of XYZ)` to store them during capture phase.  Dont bother naming them until you sort them out and decide which to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saving the images to files as you go?...or just keeping them in memory?

Depending on your answer...

You could do this:

```
Public Class MicroscopeCapture
    Public X, Y, Z As Integer
    Public FileName As String
End Class

Public Captures As New List(Of MicroscopeCapture)
```

Or possibly this:

```
Public Class MicroscopeCapture
    Public X, Y, Z As Integer
    Public MicroscopeImage As Image
End Class

Public Captures As New List(Of MicroscopeCapture)
```

---------- Edit ----------

Here's a quick example demonstrating how to grab a set from the List with a specific x,y and ordered by Z:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Resources

Public Class Form1

    Private R As New Random

    Public Class MicroscopeCapture

        Public X, Y, Z As Integer
        Public FileName As String

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("({0}, {1}, {2}) - {3}", X, Y, Z, FileName)
        End Function

    End Class

    Public Captures As New List(Of MicroscopeCapture)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim counter As Integer
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5 ' load up five sets of differnt random microscope capture groups
            Dim x As Integer = R.Next(100)
            Dim y As Integer = R.Next(100)
            Dim z As Integer = R.Next(10, 21)
            For focus As Integer = 1 To z
                counter = counter + 1
                Dim mc As New MicroscopeCapture() With {.X = x, .Y = y, .Z = focus, .FileName = "File" & counter.ToString("00000")}
                Captures.Add(mc)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' grab a random (x, y) coord from the captures:
        Dim index As Integer = R.Next(Captures.Count)
        Dim x As Integer = Captures(index).X
        Dim y As Integer = Captures(index).Y

        ' grab all the captures with the x,y values sorted by z:
        Dim captureSet As List(Of MicroscopeCapture) = GetCaptures(x, y)
        For Each mc As MicroscopeCapture In captureSet
            Debug.Print(mc.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCaptures(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As List(Of MicroscopeCapture)
        Return Captures.Where(Function(cap) cap.X = x).Where(Function(cap) cap.Y = y).OrderBy(Function(cap) cap.Z).ToList
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the Tips, it would be more like the first one since I will have lots of images I don't want to fill up the memory of the system very quickly. With the List of X, Y and Z how can I loop through the Z for each X and Y point? - Many Thanks